# Creating UIButtons dynamically - Logic Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `NSMutableArray`, and i have saving some string values in it. The size of the `NSMutableArray` could vary from 2-5 (Meaning it might have 2 -5 string values stored in it).

Depending on the count of the `NSMutableArray` i need to initialize UIBUttons and then set the value of the String stored init to the buttons title.

```
int numberOfButtonsToBeInitialize= [mutableArr count];// we are finding the number of buttons to be initialize and we assign it to a variable.
```

Now i need to create buttons (what ever the number returned by  `numberOfButtonsToBeInitialize`)

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  for(int i=0;i<numberOfButtonsToBeInitialize;i++){
  //init the button
  UIButton *bout = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        //set the title 
        [bout setTitle:[mutableArr objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [bout addTarget:self action:@selector(event:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:bout ];
        //then you can set the position of your button
        [bout setFrame:CGRectMake(70,3, 40,40)];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *myButtonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
UIButton *tmpButton;
for (NSString *bTitle in mutableArr)
{
    tmpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [tmpButton setTitle:bTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Any additional  setup goes here
    [myButtonsArray addObject:tmpButton];
}
```

Now you have an array with all the buttons. You can just iterate this array and add any button as a subview in your main view.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `for` loop. For example:

```
float buttonWidth=50;
float margin=5;
for (int index=0; index<numberOfButtonsToBeInitialize;index++)
{
    UIButton* button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    NSString* buttonTitle=[mutablearr objectAtIndex:index];
    [button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0+(buttonWidth+margin)*index, 0, buttonWidth, 30)];
    [button setTag:100+index];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

In this case we layout buttons in a row(horizontally). Adjust to your own preferences